# How to select the id of the first div inside the div jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this `<div>`

```
<div id="category_choice"></div>
```

When the category item `<div>` is clicked on, it .appends a

```
<div id="sports" class="category_item" onclick="addCategory('Sports/Health')">
    <div id="sports_thumb" class="category_thumb"></div>
    <p>Sports/Health</p>
</div>
```

inside of it. Now, when I click the submit button, it has to pass the id of the "category_item" inside the "category_choice" to ajax.

I have tried to do this with the following code:

```
$(document).on('click','#nsubmit', function () {
    var category = $('#category_choice:first-child').attr('id');
```

Ajax... bla-bla-bla data: category: category... Along with other data that I haven't mentioned, because it sends it fine. But the "category" remains empty. Please tell me where is the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

may be the space??

```
 $("#category_choice :first-child").attr('id')
```

or

as @David mentioned in comment

```
$('#category_choice > :first')
```

Comment: It should be noted that the following syntax does not select just the first child of `#category_choice` as the selector may seem to imply, but *any* element that is a descendant of `#category_choice` and that is also the first child of its parent. The fact that this works is incidental to the fact that `.attr` just grabs the first element when executed over a set of elements. It may be neater to use a selector like `$('#category_choice > :first')`

Comment: @DavidHedlund true david.Edited the post.